# Rails - Where to store a sql file with data that goes into the DB

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, convention

I have used the seed file to generate data that needs to go into the DB, but now I need to generate some countries, provinces and cities into three different tables and I haven't been able to find a good way to put that into the seed.

However I have found a sql file that has all that information and that I should dump into the DB.  My question is:

Where should I store that in my Rails folder as a convention?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a directory at db/seeds, and place that seed file, and any others you may have in there.